# Thread safety Parallel.For c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, for-loop, parallel-processing

im frenchi so sorry first sorry for my english .

I have an error on visual studio (index out of range) i have this problem only with a Parallel.For not with classic for.

I think one thread want acces on my array[i] and another thread want too ..

It's a code for calcul Kmeans clustering for building link between document (with cosine similarity).

more information :

- IndexOutOfRange is on similarityMeasure[i]=.....
- I have a computer with 2 Processor (12logical)
- with classic for , cpu usage is 9-14% , time for 1 iteration=9min..
- with parallel.for , cpu usage is 70-90% =p, time for 1 iteration =~1min30
- Sometimes it works longer before generating an error

My function is :

```
    private static int FindClosestClusterCenter(List<Centroid> clustercenter, DocumentVector obj)
{
    float[] similarityMeasure = new float[clustercenter.Count()];
    float[] copy = similarityMeasure;
    object sync = new Object();

  Parallel.For(0, clustercenter.Count(), (i) =>      //for(int i = 0; i < clustercenter.Count(); i++)  Parallel.For(0, clustercenter.Count(), (i) =>  //
       {
                similarityMeasure[i] = SimilarityMatrics.FindCosineSimilarity(clustercenter[i].GroupedDocument[0].VectorSpace, obj.VectorSpace);

       });

    int index = 0;
    float maxValue = similarityMeasure[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < similarityMeasure.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (similarityMeasure[i] > maxValue)
        {
            maxValue = similarityMeasure[i];
            index = i;
        }

    }
    return index;
}
```

My function is call here :

```
do
            {
                prevClusterCenter = centroidCollection;
                DateTime starttime = DateTime.Now;

                  foreach (DocumentVector obj in documentCollection)//Parallel.ForEach(documentCollection, parallelOptions, obj =>//foreach (DocumentVector obj in documentCollection)
                   {

                       int ind = FindClosestClusterCenter(centroidCollection, obj);

                       resultSet[ind].GroupedDocument.Add(obj);

                   }
                TimeSpan tempsecoule = DateTime.Now.Subtract(starttime);
                Console.WriteLine(tempsecoule);
                //Console.ReadKey();
                InitializeClusterCentroid(out centroidCollection, centroidCollection.Count());
                centroidCollection = CalculMeanPoints(resultSet);
                stoppingCriteria = CheckStoppingCriteria(prevClusterCenter, centroidCollection);
                if (!stoppingCriteria)
                {
                    //initialisation du resultat pour la prochaine itération
                    InitializeClusterCentroid(out resultSet, centroidCollection.Count);
                }
            } while (stoppingCriteria == false);
            _counter = counter;
            return resultSet;
```

FindCosSimilarity :

```
 public static float FindCosineSimilarity(float[] vecA, float[] vecB)
        {
            var dotProduct = DotProduct(vecA, vecB);
            var magnitudeOfA = Magnitude(vecA);
            var magnitudeOfB = Magnitude(vecB);
            float result = dotProduct / (float)Math.Pow((magnitudeOfA * magnitudeOfB),2);
            //when 0 is divided by 0 it shows result NaN so return 0 in such case.
            if (float.IsNaN(result))
                return 0;
            else
                return (float)result;

        }
```

CalculMeansPoint :

```
 private static List<Centroid> CalculMeanPoints(List<Centroid> _clust)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _clust.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (_clust[i].GroupedDocument.Count() > 0)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < _clust[i].GroupedDocument[0].VectorSpace.Count(); j++)
                    {
                        float total = 0;
                        foreach (DocumentVector vspace in _clust[i].GroupedDocument)
                        {
                            total += vspace.VectorSpace[j];
                        }

                        _clust[i].GroupedDocument[0].VectorSpace[j] = total / _clust[i].GroupedDocument.Count();
                    }
                }
            }
            return _clust;
        }
```

Comment: which line has the error? Is it `similarityMeasure[i] = ...`

Comment: Yes  "IndexOutOfRange is on similarityMeasure[i]=....."  :)

Comment: If you use an actual function call in your lambda instead of an anonymous method then you should be able to see what value i is when it breaks. That could help you find out more about the problem.

Comment: Don't `lock` in `Parallel.For` - the way you're doing things, the body of the `Parallel.For` can never execute in parallel. The code you're showing doesn't have the problem you're reporting. Please check that the code is in fact the one that's causing your trouble. Oh, and `clustercenter.Count()` obviously changes with time - if you want to stick to your algorithm (which seems incorrect), at least store the value in a local variable.

Comment: @Keithin8a You can see the value of `i` just as easily in an anonymous method. At least in Visual Studio, that is :)

Comment: I have try before without lock but same .. so i have search on the web and test with lock but nothing change ^^ .
I have try to set clustercenter.Count() in manualy with (int=287) but nothing change too.

Comment: @Luaan Ah, so you can. Sorry ignore that then, I was trying to debug an anonymous method yesterday and found it impossible to because I couldn't see one of the values. It was a multi line method though and it wouldn't let me step into it.

Comment: Sometines program genering an error with i=65 , i=200, i=33... it's variable ... :(

Comment: The basic rule of multi-threading is "don't go around guessing". Even if you finally do manage to make it work, it's very unlikely it will actually be safe and reliable. It also applies to programming in general, to an extent - why are you using `Count()` instead of `Count` and `Length`, for example? Why use `out` instead of return values? Why `stoppingCriteria == false` instead of `!stoppingCriteria`? And most importantly, *where* does the `IndexOutOfRange` actually occur? :)

Comment: Actually, looking through your code, it's obvious that the inner `Parallel.For` does not in fact run in parallel, but the outer `Parallel.ForEach` will - and `resultSet[ind].GroupedDocument.Add(obj);` *certainly* isn't thread-safe.

Comment: Ty for ur help,
Has i say, indexOutofRange sometimes genering program error with i=65, i=35... its totaly random

Comment: "My function is call here :" what function? `FindCosineSimilarity`? Please post complete function. Its hard to tell what is local or field.

Comment: As you can see i have try to Parallel.ForEach on
foreach (DocumentVector obj in documentCollection)
                   {
                   int ind = FindClosestClusterCenter(centroidCollection, obj);
                       resultSet[ind].GroupedDocument.Add(obj);
                   }

Comment: Function call is : FindClosestClusterCenter(centroidCollection, obj);
in the foreach ; 
And i want parallel for in this function,  for more speed calculate distance

Comment: And does the problem appear without the `Parallel.ForEach`, and does the CPU usage still climb to 90%? If that is the case, there's yet another level of parallelism hidden somewhere, because the `lock (sync)` simply prevents any parallelism in the `Parallel.For` itself. Also, try separating the code by lines, so that you can tell exactly which array access is the one causing the `IndexOutOfRangeException`. It could be `similarityMeasure[i]`, or `clustercenter[i]`, or `GroupedDocument[0]` or even something inside one of those method calls or properties if they're considered "not your code".

Comment: Please show rest of `FindCosineSimilarity`

Comment: I have retry run the program and he end it with no error, i retry and i have an error, (same). I have take a picture for u
http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=913565Sanstitre.jpg

Comment: I have Edit my post for show FindCosineSimilarity

Answer (score 1):

You may have some side effects in `FindCosineSimilarity`, make sure it does not modify any field or input parameter. Example: `resultSet[ind].GroupedDocument.Add(obj);`. If `resultSet` is not a reference to locally instantiated array, then that is a [side effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29).

That may fix it. But FYI you could use `AsParallel` for this rather than `Parallel.For`:

```
similarityMeasure = clustercenter
      .AsParallel().AsOrdered()
      .Select(c=> SimilarityMatrics.FindCosineSimilarity(c.GroupedDocument[0].VectorSpace, obj.VectorSpace))
      .ToArray();
```

Comment: Even if `resultSet` is local, it might very well be a reference to some other field (like, say, the `clustercenter[i]` used later). Or the `GroupedDocument` in `resultSet` might be the same reference as the one in `clustercenter[i]`. When dealing with reference types, "local" doesn't quite cut it :/

Comment: @Luaan good point, have changed to "reference to locally instantiated array"

Comment: Ty, but i have an error on .AsArray()   
'System.Linq.Parallel.Query<float>  has no definition for AsArray

Comment: @Lilianurvoy sorry, I meant to write `ToArray`

Comment: @Weston i have test with ToArray() , first time it's works (faster) but second time, same error

Comment: Yes, that is not a solution, just an FYI. Now that I can see `FindCosineSimilarity` I can not see what is wrong.

Comment: It makes no sense to me how you can get `IndexOutOfRange` please post full message and stack trace.

Comment: it's a print screen : http://hpics.li/dbaf7d2

in english error is : " the index was except(off) limits. He was have to be negative and must be lower than the size of the collection \r\nNom of the parameter: index "

Comment: I have debug and i have an error when `clustercenter[i].GroupedDocument.Count == 0`
Because he want to compare the vector space of object in `clustercenter[i].GroupedDocument` with `obj.vectorspace` and i don't understand why `clustercenter[i].GroupedDocument.Count == 0`

Comment: Well I don't have enough information to help with that. I'd debug where the `GroupedDocument` gets set or loaded.

Comment: What type is `GroupedDocument`?

Comment: `class Centroid
    {
        public List<DocumentVector> GroupedDocument { get; set; }
    }`

It's here where i stock document of centroid

Comment: @Weston    Okaaayyy i think i have found where the problem is, in the method `CalculMeanPoints(List<Centroid> _clust)`, i post this method on my first topic for you, if you found a solution ...

Answer (score 0):

You realize that if you synchronize the whole Content of the Parallel-For, it's just the same as having a normal synchrone for-loop, right? Meaning the code as it is doesnt do anything in parallel, so I dont think you'll have any Problems with concurrency. My guess from what I can tell is `clustercenter[i].GroupedDocument` is propably an empty Array.

Comment: Yeah, obviously. But how then does the CPU usage reach 90% with the parallel for, and how does it finish faster? I think it's most likely that the code the OP posted is not the actual code that shows the problem, but perhaps there's some weird closure over the `sync` variable or something (but why?)? :D

Comment: Ty for ur post.I want 45 clustercenter for example and clustercenter.count =45 ... So ?

Comment: sync variable is only for test to result my error ... not necessary here

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you are trying to say @Lilian. Maybe you could add an tracing of all array-sizes you are trying to Access to your code? Or just test the field before accessing it? (if(`clustercenter[i].GroupedDocument.Length == 0) doSomething();`  - you get what I mean)  @Luaan dont trust stats you didn't fake yourself ;-) no, jokes aside I dont know what happened there I doubt that this code up there runs in parallel.

Comment: I have test with classic For and i have the same error ... =O
Index Problem on object number "1" (first object on my list) after 6 iteration 
This time  i=33

GroupedDocument[32]=100

GroupedDocument[33]=0

GroupedDocument[34]=5

Comment: yeah as we thought it's not likely to be a concurrency Problem, at some Point you are just accessing a field for a index out of its range. I cant comment down in the other reply because of rep. but use ToArray() instead of AsArray and it will propably work to the same extend as what you are currently doing.

Comment: I have test with @weston method and replace AsArray() => .ToArray(), first time it's works, second .. same error 

But first time it's works very fast ~9sec for 1 iteration